# Python File opening syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

In Python 2.7, what is the difference between the two statements:

```
f = open("file_name", "r")
f = open("file_name").read()
```

I know both are opening a file, but is first opening the file in read mode and the latter is opening the file and then reading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first will return an open file object in read mode.

The second will return the *contents* of an open file object in read mode.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open("file_name", "r")
f = open("file_name").read()
```

The second is same as writing f = open("file_name", 'r').read().

As per python documentation the *mode* is an optional parameter to open(). If it is not specified, the file is open in read mode.

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second
>   argument is another string containing a few characters describing the
>   way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will
>   only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same
>   name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data
>   written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the
>   file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r'
>   will be assumed if it’s omitted.